# Azure Logic Apps + WCF Relay?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-relay

I'm almost giving up here - how do I connect a Logic App to a Service Bus WCF Relay running on-prem?

Following an (incomplete) tutorial on MSDN/MS Docs, I've successfully create a host and client app that communicate with each other via an Azure WCF Relay. Now, I want a Logic App to communicate with the host on my dev box.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to connect to on-prem data sources:
If the services are accessible over the internet then you call service endpoint over HTTP or HTTPS from azure logic apps. This article will help you with details steps to be followed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http

If it is not accessible over the internet then this article will help with step by step process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection

Before you can access data sources on premises from your logic apps, you need to create an Azure resource after you install the [on-premises data gateway on a local computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install). Your logic apps then use this Azure gateway resource in the triggers and actions provided by the [on-premises connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/apis-list#on-premises-connectors)  that are available for Azure Logic Apps.

[image]

Also check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#gateway-cloud-service)